# Can I allow a remote user to log into my MacBook Pro laptop as an Admin?

Tags: mac, administrator, remote-control

Hoping there is a simple way for a user to log into my Mac as an Admin remotely. I need them to be able to gain access to all the user's files whenever I am online.

So far, it seems they have to log in physically on my computer as an Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where a user logs in from doesn’t change their permissions.  If the user has Admin rights locally, they will have Admin rights when logging in remotely.

> I need them to be able to gain access to all the user's files whenever I am online.

#### This is an *ownership* issue, not an Admin issue.

If you examine the permissions and ownership of any file - use *Get Info* <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> in the GUI or `ls -la` in Terminal - you will see the permissions indicated as who can/cannot read, write or execute the file.

For example, in Terminal, I created a couple test files with different permissions for illustration:

```
% ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 allan  staff    64B Jan 30 21:45 testDir
-rw-r--r--  1 allan  staff   860B Jan 22 16:30 testfile1.txt
-rw-rw----  1 allan  staff     0B Jan 30 21:39 testfile2.txt
```

All file entries begin with a `-rw….`. The first position is whether or not it’s a directory; the first line shows this.  The next three positions are for the owner, in this case, the owner can read write and execute within the directory.  The next three are for members of the group; they can only read and execute in the directory.  The final three positions are for “everyone else;” they also have read and execute permissions.

The owner and group is denoted by the next two entries: `allan staff`.  Their permissions are set by the preceding bits.  Anywhere you see a dash `-` that means the permission is not set.

#### Get access to the file with permissions

So that the user with Admin rights has access to “all the users files” you need to either take ownership or join the appropriate group (like `staff`) and modify the permissions of the file.  I recommend the latter because you don’t want to arbitrarily take ownership of a file created by someone else as it could lead to all sorts of confusion later on.

To change the permission of the file, use the `chmod` command.  For example, to change the permissions of `testfile1.txt` so that both the owner and staff have read/write permissions, issue the command:

```
% chmod 664 testfile1.txt
% ls -la testfile1.txt
total 1
-rw-rw-r--  1 allan  staff   860B Jan 22 16:30 testfile1.txt
```

Where did the `664` come from?  That another discussion, but for now, just use the online [Chmod Calculator](https://chmod-calculator.com/).